# Calculate UITableViewCell height programmatically text containing "<br>" or "\n"

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, row-height

I want to calculate the cell height using code. My text contains html entities like `<br>,<b>` etc. I tried the following or similar code -

```
//create a CGFloat variable
CGFloat _height = 0;
//find out the size for your text. Instead of 255 insert the width of your label
CGSize _textSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:kFontSize] constrainedToSize:(CGSize) { 255, 9999 }];
//add the height of that CGSize variable to your height in case you will need to add more values
_height += _textSize.height;
```

it works fine for single line code and plain text but having issues with text containing html tags.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tutorial related to Cell Height, ang try some googling for this
http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/

Comment: I tried the same code but as i mention in my question that it work fine with text without html tags like <br> but have some issues with html text.

Comment: I have the same problem... I have markup in my code and \n to create breaks in the Cell content. The code causes the space to be much greater than the depth of the content.

Comment: @ViscusAol if this answer does not solve your question why have you marked it as the right one?